# Notation to specify crossed random effects in mixed effects model in Python

Tags: python, mixed-models, random-effects

I'm trying to model a binary response variable based on some continuous variables (fixed effects) and categorical variables (random effects).

Here is the model equation: Y<sub>ijk</sub>=*β* *X*<sub>*i*</sub> + *Z*<sub>*j*</sub> + *Z*<sub>*k*</sub> + *ε*.

Y<sub>ijk</sub>: whether the session I got a click or not

*X*<sub>*i*</sub>: fixed effect features of customer in session I: num_purchases_cat1, num_purchases_cat2, num_purchases_cat3

*Z*<sub>*j*</sub>: random effect: ad_category (100 categories)

*Z*<sub>*k*</sub>: random effect: ad_price (5 buckets)

Say my data_train contains all these columns: [clicked, num_purchases_cat1, num_purchases_cat2, num_purchases_cat3, ad_category, ad_price]. The two random effects ad_category and ad_price are independent and hence I'd like to fit a crossed effects mixed effects model.

[Python's Documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/mixed_linear.html#technical-documentation) states that I need to treat the entire dataset as a single group so here's what I'm trying:

```py
import statsmodels.regression.mixed_linear_model as mlm
lmm = mlm.MixedLM(data_train.clicked, data_train[['num_purchases_cat1', 'num_purchases_cat2', 'num_purchases_cat3']], groups=np.ones(data_train.shape[0]))
```

Now I'm struggling how to specify `exog_re` and `exog_vc`. Do I simply put `data_train[['ad_category','ad_price']]` or should I transform it to one-hot-encoding? How does this change if I want to have **Random slopes** vs **Random Intercepts** only?